# How create an array (1,6,6,1) from an array (6,6,1) without numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I create an array (1, 6, 6, 1) from an array (6, 6, 1) without use numpy?

I Tried:

```
board.reshape((1,6,6,1))
```

But doesn't work.

Here you can find a sample input: The array that I want to change looks like this:

```
[[[0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [1.]
  [0.]]

 [[0.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [0.]]

 [[0.]
  [4.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [4.]
  [0.]]

 [[0.]
  [4.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [4.]
  [0.]]

 [[0.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [0.]]

 [[0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]]]
```

Can someone help me with 'newaxis'?

Comment: Sample input and output please

Comment: Can you also add the expected output?

Comment: @Praveenkumar I just want to add a dimension, I need it as a input fro a conv NN

Comment: @Davide I am not much into ML. However, i think you can do this `print([[input] for i in range(1)])`, where `input` is the total list and `range(1)` is the axis count that you require, 1 for (1 6 6 1) and 2 for (2 6 6 1) and so on. Let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: What's `board`?  If it is a numpy `ndarray` that should work.  Does `board.shape` work?  `dtype`?  Why the `without numpy` qualifier?